# visual studio 2022 hot reload in ue5 not working

Tags: visual-studio-2022, unreal-engine5

For some reason, every time I make any kind of change to my code in visual studio 2022 and click hot reload, it gives me a window saying changes were made which cannot be compiled. I have attached an image of it to this question. I know this isn't an error in the code I'm changing because when i restart the program it works without a hitch, but obviously restarting unreal engine 5 every time you miss a semi-colon or something isn't very efficient.
[window that keeps showing up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6o9E.png)

I am also experiencing an error saying edit and continue isn't enabled:
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       'Kirito.h' in 'UnrealEditor-saofb.dll' was not compiled with Edit and Continue enabled. Ensure that the file is compiled with the Program Database for Edit and Continue (/ZI) option at Project Properties > C/C++ > Debug Information Format.     Edit and Continue

however i have checked the debugging>general settings and edit and continue is definitely enabled. I don't really know what else i can try to do about hot reload as no one has given me any answer on unreal engine discord servers.

nvm i fixed it i just had to open unreal engine on it's own and press ctrl alt f11 when i want to compile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Developing Unreal Engine code with hot reload couldnt catch the aim of existance. Thus its strictly adviced as not to use it.

- Can use "Live Coding" (This is still in experimental)
- Increase the efficiency of your environment by [link](https://dev.epicgames.com/community/learning/tutorials/Revm/unreal-engine-how-to-optimize-c-compile-time-increase-efficiency-of-intellisense).

I suggest to you to use Rider for UE development and always if you change something in code, recompile your project. In this case, even you do not cycle in your implementations when your implementation is actually working but its not reflected in Unreal and then consequence is to lost 10 hours.